# $\int_0^1\arctan\,_4F_3\left(\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5};\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{x}{64}\right)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

I need help with calculating this integral:
$$\int_0^1\arctan\,_4F_3\left(\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5};\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{x}{64}\right)\,\mathrm dx,$$
Where $_pF_q$ is a [generalized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html).

I was told it has a closed-form representation in terms of elementary functions and integers.

Comment: @Laila Maybe this hypergeometric function can be expressed in terms of elementary functions? Have you tried to find such representation?

Comment: Look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html), starting from "An infinite family of rational values"...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This hypergeometric function is not an elementary function, but its inverse **is** - see [Bring radical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Series_representation).

\begin{align}
I&= \int_0^1\arctan{_4F_3}\left(\frac15,\frac25,\frac35,\frac45;\frac12,\frac34,\frac54;\frac{x}{64}\right)\,dx \\
&=\frac{3125}{48}\left(5+3\pi+6\ln2-3\alpha^4+4\alpha^3+6\alpha^2-12\alpha\\-12\left(\alpha^5-\alpha^4+1\right)\arctan\frac1\alpha-6\ln\left(1+\alpha^2\right)\right)\\
&=0.7857194\dots
\end{align}
where $\alpha$ is the positive root of the polynomial $625\alpha^4-500\alpha^3-100\alpha^2-20\alpha-4$. It can be expressed in radicals as follows:

$$\alpha=\frac15+\sqrt\beta+\sqrt{\frac15-\beta +\frac1{25\sqrt\beta}},$$
where
$$\beta=\frac1{30}\left(\frac\gamma5-\frac4\gamma+2\right),$$
where
$$\gamma=\sqrt[3]{15\sqrt{105}-125}.$$

Comment: Of course, you can express $\pi$ as $4 \arctan 1$ to get rid of non-integer constants.

Comment: Commiserations to anyone who attempted this by hand.

Comment: That's so obvious, I an kicking myself (very softly) for not thinking of it.

Comment: @L.F. I recalculated the integral completely by hand, and now the result looks much nicer.

Comment: This is a true marvel...!

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: +1 I added an equivalent form. I hope its ok. The polynomial in $\alpha$ had a cube factor and $\alpha$ also had a shorter and "natural" defining polynomial as $\alpha^4(1-\alpha)=\frac4{3125}$.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov: I reverted my edits as I asked a [generalized question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081467/on-int-01-arctan-6f-5-left-frac17-frac27-frac37-frac47-frac57-frac67).