# Integral $\int_0^\infty\left(x+5\,x^5\right)\operatorname{erfc}\left(x+x^5\right)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, error-function

Is it possible to find a closed form (possibly using known special functions) for this integral?
$$\int_0^\infty\left(5\,x^5+x\right)\operatorname{erfc}\left(x^5+x\right)\,dx$$
where $\operatorname{erfc}$ is [the complementary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html)
$$\operatorname{erfc} x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^{\infty}e^{-z^2}dz.$$

Comment: The Maple command $$evalf(Int((5*x^5+x)*erfc(x^5+x), x = 0 .. infinity), 50); $$ outputs $0.21195392584162642127934513122200307521311778875987 $.

Comment: Integrating by parts a few times, the integral under consideration can be expressed through [$erfc(x,n)$](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=erf).

Comment: $\operatorname{erfc}(n,\,x)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ can be expressed using just $\operatorname{erfc}(x)$ and elementary functions.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With some help from *Mathematica* I got this result:
$$\int_0^\infty\left(5\,x^5+x\right)\operatorname{erfc}\left(x^5+x\right)dx=J_{\frac25}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)\left(\frac8{375}\sqrt{\frac25\left(5-\sqrt5\right)}\,\pi\,J_{\frac45}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)-\frac8{375}\sqrt{\frac25\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}\,\pi\,J_{\frac65}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)\right)+J_{-\frac25}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)\left(\frac1{75}\sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}\,\pi\,J_{-\frac15}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)+\frac1{25}\left(\sqrt5-5\right)\sqrt{\frac1{10}\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}\,\pi\,J_{\frac15}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)-\frac8{375}\sqrt{\frac25\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}\,\pi\,J_{\frac45}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)-\frac{4\left(\sqrt5-5\right)\sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}\,\pi\,J_{\frac65}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)}{1875}\right)+J_{-\frac15}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)\left(\frac1{25}\sqrt{2\left(5-\sqrt5\right)}\,\pi\,J_{\frac25}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)+\frac8{375}\sqrt{\frac25\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}\,\pi\,J_{\frac35}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)-\frac8{375}\sqrt{\frac25\left(5-\sqrt5\right)}\,\pi\,J_{\frac75}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)\right)+J_{\frac15}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)\left(-\frac1{75}\sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}\,\pi\,J_{\frac25}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)+\frac{4\left(\sqrt5-5\right)\sqrt{2\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}\,\pi\,J_{\frac35}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)}{1875}+\frac8{375}\sqrt{\frac25\left(5+\sqrt5\right)}\,\pi\,J_{\frac75}\left(\frac8{25\sqrt5}\right)\right),$$
where $J_\nu(x)$ is the [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).

---

*A solution outline:*

Note that $(5\,x^5+x)=x\frac{d}{dx}(x^5+x)$. Change the integration variable $y=x^5+x$, then the integral takes the form
$$\int_0^\infty\mathcal{BR}(y)\cdot\operatorname{erfc}y\,dy,$$
where $y\mapsto\mathcal{BR}(y)$ is the inverse (properly selected to satisfy $\mathcal{BR}(y)>0$ for $y>0$) of the polynomial function $x \mapsto x^5+x$.  This is a well-known non-elementary function called [Bring radical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Series_representation), it can be used to express solutions of quintic equations in an explicit form.

An important fact, it has a representation via a generalized hypergeometric function (I used it to [answer another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/388916/19661) awhile ago). If we plug the hypergeometric representation into the integral and feed it to *Mathematica*, it produces the result in terms of Bessel functions shown above. I leave this step without a rigorous proof and rely on *Mathematica* here. The result agrees with a numerical integration to a very high precision. I would be very glad if anybody could write down an explicit derivation of the formula.

Comment: (+1) ... but how do you get that result with Mathematica while I am getting nothing??

Comment: @SantoshLinkha It depends: do you use the serious Mathematica or Alpha? Also it depends on your computer power.

Answer (score 11):

Hint:

$\int_0^\infty(5x^5+x)\text{erfc}(x^5+x)~dx$

$=\int_0^\infty\text{erfc}(x^5+x)~d\left(\dfrac{5x^6}{6}+\dfrac{x^2}{2}\right)$

$=\left[\left(\dfrac{5x^6}{6}+\dfrac{x^2}{2}\right)\text{erfc}(x^5+x)\right]_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty\left(\dfrac{5x^6}{6}+\dfrac{x^2}{2}\right)d(\text{erfc}(x^5+x))$

$=\int_0^\infty\left(\dfrac{5x^6}{6}+\dfrac{x^2}{2}\right)(5x^4+1)\dfrac{2e^{-x^2(x^8+1)}}{\sqrt\pi}dx$

$=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-(\sinh^\frac{1}{2}x)(\sinh^2x+1)}\left(\dfrac{5\sinh^\frac{3}{2}x}{6}+\dfrac{\sinh^\frac{1}{2}x}{2}\right)(5\sinh x+1)~d(\sinh^\frac{1}{4}x)$

$=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-\sinh^\frac{1}{2}x\cosh^2x}~\left(\dfrac{5\sinh^\frac{3}{2}x}{6}+\dfrac{\sinh^\frac{1}{2}x}{2}\right)(5\sinh x+1)\sinh^{-\frac{3}{4}}x\cosh x~dx$

That's why it may relate to Bessel function.